# R: How to use approx in more than one dimension (multidimensional interpolation)?

Tags: r

This should no be to hard, but I searched a lot and did not find a solution so far...

I am dealing with some scattered data where

```
y = f(x1,x2,x3,..., xn)
```

I would like to create a lookup function, which gives me the exact known values of `y` when entering a vector `x` which is in the data set, but linearly interpolates when the vector `x` was not in the data set.

Basically like `approx()`, but for higher number of dimensions.

To ease any tryouts, here is some data:

```
y<-rnorm(27)
x1<-seq(1,3,1)
x2<-seq(10,30,10)
x3<-seq(100,300,100)

df<-expand.grid(x1,x2,x3)
df<-cbind(y,df)
names(df)<-c("y","x1","x2","x3")

# Task is to create a function like
#   fun(x1,x2,x3) --> interpolated y

# expected output example:
# fun(1,10,100) --> -0.89691454
# fun(1.5,10,100) --> -0.3560327
```

Comment: Shouldn't "y" be of `length(y) == nrow(expand.grid(x1, x2, x3))`? Perhaps, you could, also, add an example output for `fun`? E.g. `fun(1, 20, 100) --> ?`, `fun(1.2, 15.45, 102) --> ?`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added an example.